# How to create an action from selecting a row from an perticular column (Not all the column) NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have one table view which have four columns, fourth columns is populating with attributes string, I need to call one action whenever click on row of fourth column

In others word whiner i click on fourth column's row at that time only action should call

for entire row i am able to do that but for perticullar column not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to subclass NSTableView and handle mouseDown

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint globalLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:globalLocation fromView:nil];
    NSInteger clickedRow = [self rowAtPoint:localLocation];
    NSInteger clickedCol = [self columnAtPoint:localLocation];
    if (clickedCol == 3) //... fourth column
    //.... do something with clickeRow and clickedCol
}
```

You could create a custom delegate to inform the class' owner that a particular row-col combination has been clicked.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{

    if(indexPath.row==3)
    {

    //DO your action here 

    }
}
```